# HTML CSS: Align Pieces in Text Box, Header Top and Description in Middle

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, text

How do I align two different pieces of text in a box? I would like Header to be on Top, and Description to be in middle. See below. Align Self-center moves description in the middle, however trying to make Header on top regardless of box size.

Goal to keep description static in middle, regardless of title overflow.

```css
.grid-container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 140px 140px;
        grid-template-rows: 140px;
        align-items: stretch;

    }

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.test
{
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:center;
  align-self: center
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container" id="gridid42f08d611e2346748fbe47264fd732e0">
    <img class="imgcard mCS_img_loaded" id="imgid42f08d611e2346748fbe47264fd732e00" src="https://www.woodlandtrust.org.uk/media/100078482/Sycamore01.jpg?cb=-11897985&amp;preset=gallery-tab-main-image">
    <div class="test"> Header <br> Description </div>
</div>
```

**Goal:**

[image]

test

Comment: You need to have your header and description in separate, semantically correct elements. Why not use a heading and a paragraph?

Comment: You'll hit another wall when your text in *header* will exceed the size, having to push *description* off-middle. And don't say that it will never happen ;) - Otherwise, using absolute position it will overlap.

Comment: chiller solution is good below, if I want option keep description in center, if header lines kept increasing, how would that be conducted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flex box to organize your element and align theme accordingly

See code snippet:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 140px 140px;
  grid-template-rows: 140px;
  align-items: stretch;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.test {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.description {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container" id="gridid42f08d611e2346748fbe47264fd732e0">
  <img class="imgcard mCS_img_loaded" id="imgid42f08d611e2346748fbe47264fd732e00" src="https://www.woodlandtrust.org.uk/media/100078482/Sycamore01.jpg?cb=-11897985&amp;preset=gallery-tab-main-image">
  <div class="test">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="description"> Description</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: also, if I wanted option keep description in center, if header lines kept increasing, how would that be conducted?

Comment: well, I want header line to grow not stay in one line, will let user space out correctly before it collides with description

Comment: code above makes description move down as header keeps growing,

Comment: keep description in middle , let header keep growing in multiple lines

Comment: Its what i would expect to work, why is it a problem?

Comment: yeah, was just trying to make description center static, current trying to google, align center, vertical align, etc,  thanks